# Multiple Cucumber features in one file

Tags: spring-boot, bdd, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I've created a cucumber feature file as follows

```
Feature: Managing Students
Scenario: Manage Students page
Given Open browser and launch application
And Home page is displayed
When User clicks on Manage Students link
Then User sees Manage Students page


Scenario: Create Students Page
Given Click on Add student button
And New form is displayed
Then Enter details in the form
Then Click submit
```

And a Java file as follows

```
@SneakyThrows
@When("^User clicks on Manage Students link$")
public void clickOnManagerStudentsLink(){
    String manageStudentsBtnText = webDriver.findElement(By.id("manage-students-btn")).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue(manageStudentsBtnText.equalsIgnoreCase("Manage Students"));
    webDriver.findElement(By.id("manage-students-btn")).click();
}

@SneakyThrows
@Then("^User sees Manage Students page$")
public void userSeesManageStudentsPage(){
    String manageStudentsBtnText = webDriver.findElement(By.id("add-student-btn")).getText();
    Assert.assertTrue(manageStudentsBtnText.equalsIgnoreCase("Add Student"));
}

@SneakyThrows
@Given("^Click on Add student button$")
public void clickOnAddStudentButton(){
    webDriver.findElement(By.id("add-student-btn")).click();
    Assert.assertTrue(webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(),'Add Student')]")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Add Student"));
}
```

Now, when I run a test file, the first scenario executes perfectly, but when it comes to first line of clickOnAddStudentButton() it throws NullPointerException. TIA.

Comment: webDriver instance is available in test case?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal yes, thank you for pointing it out. But why? The above cases work perfect but when it comes to last one it becomes null, is it because every scenario needs to have a separate file with steps in it?

Comment: Sounds like somehow you are not creating/reusing your WebDriver in every scenario. How is impossible to say, you didn't include that code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example